# How to parse a string of format "YYYYMMDD" to a Timex.Parse.DateTime type?

Tags: date, parsing, elixir

I want to use Paul Schoenfelder's awesome [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library to parse a simple string of format "YYYYMMDD" into a `Timex.Parse.DateTime.t` type.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
{:ok, dt} = Timex.parse "20161111", "{YYYYDDMM}"
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:format, "Expected at least one parser to succeed at line 1, column 0."}}
```

This code above, doesn't work. But when I do this:

```
{:ok, dt} = Timex.parse "2016", "{YYYY}"        
{:ok, #<DateTime(2016-01-01T00:00:00Z)>}
```

I get `dt` assigned as a `DateTime` variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- It looks like the `DD` and `MM` are not valid parsers. You're probably looking for `0D` and `0M` (more date/month parsers available [here](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/a9c9cc6c185ee0b3e5be8f5dbc3b4711398efb65/test/parse_default_test.exs#L53-L71)).
- You need to wrap each component in their own `{}`

Running on the latest git version of Timex:

```
iex> Timex.parse "20161111", "{YYYY}{0D}{0M}"
{:ok, #<DateTime(2016-11-11T00:00:00Z)>}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.